# Question about the derivative of a contravariant tensor

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, differentiation, covariance

I need to show that $\frac{\partial T^i}{\partial x^j}$ is not a tensor.

How I proceeded and what I got was:

$\dfrac{\partial T^{i'}}{\partial x^{j'}} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{j'}} \left ( T^i J^{i'}_i \right ) = \dfrac{\partial T^i}{\partial x^j}J^{j}_{j'} J^{i'}_{i} + T^i J^{i'}_{ij} J^{j}_{j'}$,

with $J^{i'}_i \equiv \dfrac{\partial x^{i'}}{\partial x^i}$ and $J^{i'}_{ij} \equiv \dfrac{\partial² x^{i'}}{\partial x^{i} \partial x^{j}} $.

But the right answer is

$\dfrac{\partial T^{i'}}{\partial x^{j'}} = S^{ij} J^{j'}_{j} J^{i'}_{i} + T^i J^{i'}_{ij} J^{j}_{j'} $

(note only the first term differs from my answer on $J^{j'}_{j}$).

Where $S^{ij}\equiv\dfrac{\partial T^{i}}{\partial x^{j}}$.

I don't know where is my error and why is $\frac{\partial T^{i}}{\partial x^{j}}$ intepreted as a second rank contravariant tensor $S^{ij}$?

Comment: Is this homework? If so, then please use the homework-and-exercises tag.

Comment: No, its not homework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation $S^{ij}\equiv\dfrac{\partial T^i}{\partial x^j}$ is wrong!
The $x^j$ in the denominator requires $S^i_j\equiv\dfrac{\partial T^i}{\partial x^j}$
Your demo is correct.